# Jquery dialog window example not working

Tags: jquery

Trying to learn Jquery and am on the verge of giving up!! Have spent 2 days trying to get a dialog box to display!

Can anyone help as to why this code doesnt work? I just get hello at the top of the page!

jQuery:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $('#dialog')
    //.html('This dialog will show every time!')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Basic Dialog'
    });
    $('#opener').click(function() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="dialog">hello</div>
<button id="opener" style="margin-left:66px;margin-top:3px;font-size:11px;width:60px">Click</button>
```

Comment: It's a stylesheet issue. His code is fine.

Comment: Make sure you download the jQuery UI bundle with the dialog widget. Looking at your example you may have only grabbed the core.

Comment: Any chance of actually saying what I need to add and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your jQuery UI Core file has included the Widget factory.  Take a look:

***http://jqueryui.com/download***

Even if you don't have the jQuery UI CSS file included, it should still work:

***[See jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/dY5da/)***

---

***[Try this exact code that I have out at jsBin:](http://jsbin.com/ibuguv/edit#html,live)***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>jQuery Dialog Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dialog" style="display: none;">hello</div>
  <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var $dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, title: "Basic Dialog" });
    $("#opener").click(function() { $dialog.dialog("open"); });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: His code works though, it just isn't rendering. It is most likely a forgotten CSS file or not linked correctly.

Comment: I don't see how it would work without the widgets file being included.

Comment: Widget is included as part of core... Isn't it?

Comment: It works for me, I click it and it opens the dialog. You click close and it closes, etc.  Again, it's showing you that it works without the styling.  You can include the stylesheet to show the styling, but the functionality shows that it works.

Comment: It worked when you first posted it. But it doesnt work now. I have added  `<script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script> ` to my code and it still doesnt work

Comment: Oh sorry Scott. I see what you mean now. But my code (not in jsfiddler) just displays hello before I have even clicked the button. And nothing happens when i click the button!

Comment: I also get an error saying object does not support this property or method

Comment: Check my edit for a working demo with complete html markup for you to simply copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks for your help Scott! That seems to work, but I cant find where to get jquery-ui.min.js from? I have just about every other file apart from that one?

Comment: You just need to go to Microsoft's CDN. [Here is the jump to jQuery](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_Releases_on_the_CDN_0) and [Here is the jump to jQuery UI](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_UI_Releases_on_the_CDN_1)

Comment: Hi Scott! Managed to work it out. I used jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js! Thanks for your help. I think Ill persevere a bit longer with jquery and javascript! Is very hard going though! Its like programming while blindfolded! Any tips for a beginner?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com and http://jqueryui.com/demos are your friends.  They really provide in depth descriptions to each method.

Comment: Thanks again Scott! Will check them out! Appreciate yr help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you dont have your CSS stylesheets loaded.

Comment: WHich CSS stylesheet do i need?

Comment: Any chance of actually saying what I need to add and where?